# XSLT - Dynamic Map Columns

Tags: xml, xslt, cast-iron

I have 3 different XML files. Some columns of them common and someone are not. And ordinalPosition of them are changing. Each time, i get new file in my ftp and need to read one by one and load into system. But i don't know about column names of the file.

```
  XML 1 :
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SourceFile>
       <Data>
         <CustNo>126</CustNo>
         <Gender/>
         <isActive>0</isActive>
         <Email/>
       </Data>
    </SourceFile>   

XML 2 :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SourceFile>
   <Data>
    <CustNo>124</CustNo>
    <Phone/>
    <Country/>
    <isActive>1</isActive>
   </Data>
 </SourceFile> 

XML 3:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SourceFile>
   <Data>
    <KeyId>123</KeyId>
    <FirstName/>
    <LastName/>
    <Email/>  
    <isActive>0</isActive>
   </Data>
 </SourceFile>
```

I am very new with XSLT. I want generate below output whenever a file arrived in my ftp.

```
  Result for XML 1 :
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SourceFile>
      <Data>
        <KeyID>124</KeyID>  <!-- CustNo will be mapped to KeyId -->
        <FirstName/>
        <LastName/>
        <Email/> 
        <Phone/>
        <Country/>
        <isActive>0</isActive> 
      </Data>
    </SourceFile>
```

Many thanks,
Mehmet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always want to have *all* the listed elements present in the output (populated or not), and that you want them in the given order, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/SourceFile">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Data">
            <xsl:copy>
                <KeyID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CustNo | KeyId"/>
                </KeyID>
                <FirstName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
                </FirstName>
                <LastName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
                </LastName>
                <Email> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="Email"/>
                </Email> 
                <Phone>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Phone"/>
                </Phone>
                <Country>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
                </Country>
                <isActive>
                    <xsl:value-of select="isActive"/>
                </isActive> 
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**One** try would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
       <xsl:copy>
           <KeyID><xsl:value-of select="CustNo | KeyId"/></KeyID>
           <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/></FirstName>
           <Email><xsl:value-of select="Email"/></Email>
           <Phone><xsl:value-of select="Phone"/></Phone>
           <Country><xsl:apply-templates select="Country"/></Country>
           <isActive><xsl:value-of select="isActive"/></isActive>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Country">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation:**

On element `Data` you always create the expected outcome. Like `KeyID`, `FirstName`, and so on.. Whenever the select of either `<xsl:value-of` or `<xsl:apply-templates` matches, you get the content of node.

`<xsl:value-of />` just returns the string of an element.

`<xsl:apply-templates />` will eventually execute other template-rules as well! This is important if you have child-nodes for example. You see this in the example for element `Country`.

XML and XSLT are case-sensitiv.